# how can i parse an image and show it in my listview?

Tags: android, parsing

I am new to android i am currently making an app which parse RSS feed and i want to also get the images of the RSs feed but did not know how can i show images in the list view along with the text.You help will be very helpful for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a `ListView` with custom views, you need to create a class that extends `BaseAdapter`. You then need to override its `getView()` method to return your custom view, in this case a view that contains an `ImageView` alongside a `TextView`. Then set an instance of this class as the adapter for your `ListView`.

This should help
[Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012)